# Rails: Creating associated records in a new parent record that has no ID yet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have page, that `has_many` pictures. However, I want to be able to upload pictures in the page's new view (before "page" has an `ID` assigned to it to use for association).

What is the best practice approach to doing this? I have done this in the past by skipping validation and saving "page" which gives me an `ID` to work with. However, i feel like that is hacky approach. as it gives me a lot of empty pages that need cleaned up.

Is there a better method to making this all work? I was thinking of storing all the id's of the pictures uploaded in an array field on the page model. And then `after_save` running through each image `ID` and building the association.

Thoughts? Recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

If the picture objects need to be saved before the parent there will always be the chance that something happens (eg: the user decided not to save it) and the page doesn't get saved afterall, and the pictures will inevitably need some cleanup as well, so you can save the Page from the beginning.

I've faced this situation multiple times and I haven't found a better approach (than the one you propose), you might want to add a 'status' field on the Page model to handle the display/cleanups.

If you find a better solution, let me know!